# Confusion of the Isobraic Process Heat equation

Tags: thermodynamics

I was currently reading a wiki article on Isobaric Process (Link at bottom f post). And am confused as to why in there derivation of heat of a an isobaric system they use specific heat capacity for volume when volume is changing and pressure is constant, so why they relating internal energy to a heat capacity of a constant volume and not pressure and how is $C_p=C_v+R$, as in my text book '*Physics for scientist and engineers*' by tippler it states that $C_p-C_v=nR$, so where has the n gone from the wiki equation?

$\underline{Screen \: Capture \: Of \: Wiki}$

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isobaric_process

Comment: This question frequently arises; see [here](http://john.maloney.org/cruelest_equation.htm) for discussion and links to other answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the specific heat at constant volume is used even though it is not a constant volume process is because it happens to be that change in internal energy for an ideal gas, for ANY process, is given by

$$\Delta U = C_v\Delta T$$

This can be derived as follows:

For a constant pressure process:

$$\Delta U=Q-W$$
$$\Delta U=C_p\Delta T – P\Delta V$$
For one mole of an ideal gas
$$P\Delta V=R\Delta T$$
Therefore 
$$ \Delta U=C_p\Delta T – R\Delta T$$

Also, for any ideal gas

$$R=C_p-C_v$$

Substituting

$$ \Delta U=C_p\Delta T – (C_p-C_v)\Delta T$$
$$\Delta U=C_v\Delta T$$

Concerning the equation for R, $C_p-C_v=R$ for one mole of an ideal gas (n=1)

We can prove that $C_p-C_v=R$ is by using the basic definitions of the specific heats and enthalpy, combined with the ideal gas law.

Specific heat definitions, ideal gas (they are actually partial derivatives holding P and V constant, respectively):
$$C_p = \frac {dH}{dT}$$
$$C_v = \frac {dU}{dT}$$
Definition of enthalpy (H)
$$H = U + PV$$
For one mole of an ideal gas, ideal gas law
$$PV=RT$$
Therefore
$$H = U+RT$$

Taking the derivative of the last equation with respect to temperature:
$$\frac {dH}{dT} =\frac {dU}{dT}+R$$
Substituting the specific heat definitions into the last equation, we get
$$C_p – C_v = R$$

Hope this helps.